# AS3 How do you scale video down?

Tags: actionscript-3, video, scaling

I have a webcam capturing video at a certain resolution, but I want to display it at a lower resolution for preview purposes.

When I scale the video down using another another video object set at this lower res, the image quality seems to be quite bad.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the video object set

```
video.smoothing = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

set `smoothing` to true and change the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties.

```
myVideo.smoothing = true;
myVideo.scaleX = myVideo.scaleY = 0.5;
```